# how only display other user ID on the two columns user 1 and user 2 after filtering authenticated user ID from the table and adding it to a new column

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm creating a one-on-one chat, but there are two columns: user 1 and user 2.
The user may be in user 1 or user 2, and I want to show him or her the chats from people who have contacted him or him, but the table returned as

[image]

and I just want to retrieve the other user id not the authenticated user, who is 51
so l want to select either user 1 or user 2 which has the other user id.

the code I implemented

```php
 $room = Chat::where([
            ['user_1',Auth::id()]
    
            ])->orWhere([
                ['user_2',Auth::id()]
            ])->latest()->get();
// dd($room);
        return view('users.chats',[
            'room_id'=>$room,
            // 'messages'=>Message::oldest()->where('chat_id',$room->chat_id)->get(),
            'selectedUser' => false
        ]);
```

How can I create a new column called "other user" and only retrieve the other user's ID?

Answer (score 0):

Running it through php on array filter fixed the problem.

```
 $room = Chat::where([
            ['user_1',Auth::id()]
    
            ])->orWhere([
                ['user_2',Auth::id()]
            ])->latest()->get();
        $users = array();
        foreach($room as $item){
           
            array_push($users,$item->user_1,$item->user_2);
        }
       
        $fillterdUsers = array_filter($users,function($val){
            return $val !== auth()->id();
        });
      
        return view('users.chats',[
            'room_id'=>$fillterdUsers,
            // 'messages'=>Message::oldest()->where('chat_id',$room->chat_id)->get(),
            'selectedUser' => false
        ]);
```